# Direct E-mails to specific addresses from dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a form that needs to be sent to separate email addresses depending on dropdown selection. I have researched and only found a few ways to achieve this by PHP. I am working in a CMS with only HTML, and CSS at access. I need this to be done in HTML, Jquery, etc.

```
<form action="/Task/Form/ProcessForm.cfm" id="contact_form_HL" method="post" name="Contact_Light" onsubmit="return validate()">

    <label>
        <span>Select The Location<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></span>
        <select class="select-input-patient" name="location">
            <option value="Alabama - Scottsboro">Alabama - Scottsboro</option>
            <option value="Georgia - Cumming">Georgia - Cumming</option>
            <option value="Georgia - Dalton">Georgia - Dalton</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</form>
```

These are an example of my values for the dropdown menu. They're 22 in total but will be growing as time progressses. I have a few more options below the above input; name, company, etc. Thank you in advance.

Yes it is not sent through a mailto:. Here is an example of another forms submit button.

```
 <input class="submit" name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
 <input name="email_subject" type="hidden" value="Contact Form" />
 <input name="email_form" type="hidden" value="Contact@contact.com" />
 <input name="email_to" type="hidden" value="Contact@contact.com" />
 <input name="email_bcc" type="hidden" value="foo@foo.com" />
 <input name="returnURL" type="hidden" value="/thankyou/" />
```

Comment: I'm guessing your emails are sent at the server, and not by poping up something with href="mailto:me@me.com".

In that case, we need to know what on the server decides where emails are sent. Is it the URL, or some parameters?

Otherwise, how would you like the email formatted?

Comment: It is either sent from the server side or via a mailto in the browser which spawns the client's email client.  It seems like you are asking for a miracle.

Comment: It is sent on the server side. So it will not be possible on my end to assign "Alabama - Scottsboro" to send to foo@scottsboro.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that it's the `email_to` field which controls where the mail is sent, you can just remove the hidden input in your example, and rename your dropdown-menu to `email_to`. The `value` property of each `option` should then be the mail address for every respective location. Like this:

```
<form action="/Task/Form/ProcessForm.cfm" id="contact_form_HL" method="post" name="Contact_Light" onsubmit="return validate()">

    <label>
        <span>Select The Location<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></span>
        <select class="select-input-patient" name="email_to">
            <option value="foo@scottsboro.com">Alabama - Scottsboro</option>
            <option value="foo@cumming.com">Georgia - Cumming</option>
            <option value="foo@dalton.com">Georgia - Dalton</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <input class="submit" name="SUBMIT" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    <input name="email_subject" type="hidden" value="Contact Form" />
    <input name="email_form" type="hidden" value="Contact@contact.com" />
    <input name="email_bcc" type="hidden" value="foo@foo.com" />
    <input name="returnURL" type="hidden" value="/thankyou/" />
</form>
```

You can of course substitute email_to to email_bcc if that's preferable.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you sir worked perfectly and just in time for the site to launch today at noon. Very much appreciated!